# Supervised learning for a turn-based game?

Tags: supervised-learning, game

So I have 4GB of turn-by-turn data for many games of a particular strategy game. It appears that most people interested in using ML to build an AI for turn-based games use reinforcement learning to build a model on the fly.

Since I already have really good data, can I use supervised learning to solve this task?

EDIT: I was considering using regression to assign a score to a given action based on its likelihood of eventually resulting in a win; is this the right way to think about it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the correct way of addressing this is by making sub optimizations of every step, even though it could be done by regression, I would suggest decision trees.

You have and advantage: A game is made of discrete steps, so in every moment you can "stop" and decide the best move based on your (possibly comprehensive) history of moves.

[Supervised learning vs reinforcement learning for a simple self driving rc car](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11126/supervised-learning-vs-reinforcement-learning-for-a-simple-self-driving-rc-car?rq=1)

Comment: Could both regression and decision trees be used? I feel like the output of the prediction of a given turn needs to be a continuous value.

Comment: Yes, you could use both of them. I don't know which game your AI is playing but is difficult to think in a game which has a continuos output of a move.

Think in Chess (for example),  the queen moves n blocks and every block has its own output. Regression is not enough to get the no-linear scoring schemas of most turn-based games.